# Cordova : Getting error while npm run build_android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus, cordova-plugins, google-plus-signin

I am working on hybrid app using android and ionic framework. I want to add login with google+ functionality so I used this [cordova-plugin-googleplus](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

Before using this plugin **npm run build_android** works good without any error but after installing this plugin it throws these error output -

```
:dexArmv7Debug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexArmv7Debug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        D:\Projects\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\Projects\wamp
\www\hybridapp\cordova\platforms\android\build\intermediates\dex\armv7\debug --input-list=D:\Projects\wamp\www\hybridapp\cordova
\platforms\android\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\armv7\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
        2
Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
                at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3 mins 29.39 secs

d:\Projects\wamp\www\hybridapp\cordova\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "d:\Projects\wamp\www\hybridapp\cordova\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
 d:\Projects\wamp\www\hybridapp\cordova\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: d:\Projects\wamp\www\hybridapp\cordova\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command f
ailed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: d:\Projects\wamp\www\hybridapp\cordova\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (c:\Users\pcs227\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\supers
pawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

How can I solve it ?

**EDIT** : These are the plugin list which are used:

```
com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.11.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.0.1-dev "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 4.0.6 "Google+"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.6 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.0 "File"
org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, this might happen when we upgrade or install a new android sdk. Try to uninstall android platform:

```
ionic platform remove android
```

and then reinstall it using:

```
ionic platform add android
```